# Nextjs is neither receiving nor sending cookie to express js bakend

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, next.js, httponly

My front end app is in nextjs that run on port 3000 locally  and backend is in express js that runs at port 3001 locally.
I used the same backend for my react js app, but there was not problem in sending or receiving cookie with react js front end. But when I hit apis from Next js, something is not working

```
cookie_detail: { 
              secure: true,
              sameSite: "Strict",
              httpOnly: true,
              expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 300 * 1000),
            },
```

This same cookie details I have sent to both react and next js,
Next js api function -

```
 const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: "Bearer " + cookie_key_name,
        // Add any other headers you need
      };
    return api.post(route, body,{headers});
```

I am not what I am doing wrong here? It is my first next js project

Comment: Could be a multitude of things: You're just sending an auth token through the `Authorization` header but not a cookie. Not sure what `api` is (assuming it's an axios instance or some form of custom fetch function), but it needs to set the axios `withCredentials: true` property or set fetch's `'credentials': 'include'` as a header. Also, you've set the cookie's `sameSite` property as [strict](https://owasp.org/www-community/SameSite), which means "...[it] will prevent the cookie from being sent by the browser to the target site in all ***cross-site browsing contexts***." Try using lax or none.

Comment: One other thing you can do to narrow the problem is to look at the outgoing request in your browser tools "Network" tab. You can look at the "Request" headers and you should see a `Cookie` header is present, like this [example](https://i.imgur.com/Qaz679N.png). If that cookie header isn't present, then it's more than __likely__ a client-side configuration problem (request configuration), but doesn't rule out a cookie setting (too restrictive).